# How do I solve "_message: 'item validation failed'" in Node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The Thing is that I am trying to display the items using router.get() method and adding an item using router.post() , I am getting an error as shown at the end of the code ...
Here is my code :

**server.js file :**

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const items = require('./routes/api/items');
app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//DB Connection
const db = require('./config/keys').MONGOURI;
mongoose.connect(db,  { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(()=>console.log("Connected."))
    .catch((err)=>console.log(err))

//Routes
app.use('/api/items', items);


app.listen(port,()=>console.log("Working."))
```

.
**Item model file:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name :{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model("item", ItemSchema);
```

Routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Item = require("../../models/Item");

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    Item.find()
    .sort({date: -1})
    .then(items => res.json(items))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
});

router.post('/', (req,res)=>{
    const newItem = new Item({
        name: req.body.name
    })
    newItem.save()
    .then(items=>res.json(items))
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
});
```

In the routes file, I am not able to store the item In the Mongo-DB database as I am getting the following error:

```
Error: item validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (D:\Projects\Full Stack\MERN\Basics\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:47:26)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:718:31)      
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:287:10)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1910:40)
    at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:299:10)
    at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:309:61)    at D:\Projects\Full Stack\MERN\Basics\routes\api\items.js:19:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  errors: {
    name: ValidatorError: Path `name` is required.        
        at validate (D:\Projects\Full Stack\MERN\Basics\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1257:13)
        at D:\Projects\Full Stack\MERN\Basics\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1240:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (D:\Projects\Full Stack\MERN\Basics\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1185:14)
        at D:\Projects\Full Stack\MERN\Basics\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2501:18
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'name',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'item validation failed'
}
```

Please help me out thank you...

Comment: what's the value of req.body.name ? is it empty ?

Comment: @KristofDcu It is the value the user will type and I will parse it using express ....So it is not empty

Comment: Yes I undertsand, but did you check in debug mode that it's correctly setted ? The error can indicate that this value in empty.

Comment: @KristofDcu OKay I will try that :)

Comment: @KristofDcu I at at last figured out the issue... I was using postman to test the API and instead of setting JSON it was accepting text so I was getting undefined.... Now That I changed it I am able to get the results :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept my answer to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicate that **property "name" is not corectly (regarding your model validation : required in your case) set when you try to save()** your new user.

Check if incomming value of **req.body.name** is correctly set.